# Extended Hypergeometric candy problem

Tags: probability

Suppose you are handing out Halloween candy to children. The bowl from which you are selecting candy contains 5 Mars bars, 6 Wunderbars, 3 Aero bars, 4 Big Turks and 1
Crispy Crunch. If you randomly select 4 candies to give each child, find the probability
that a child receives four different pieces of candy

I'm a little unsure of the setup:

$\dfrac{\binom{5}{x_m}\binom{6}{x_w}\binom{3}{x_a}\binom{4}{x_b}\binom{1}{x_c}}{\binom{19}{4}}$; where $x_m...x_c$ are the amounts of each candy bar chosen

How do I account for the different ways of choosing $1$ from each of these candy bars?

Comment: I'm still confused. Then it would seem that I'm varying $2,3,$ or $4$ between the different kinds of candy bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are distributing to the first child (since bars are limited)
Your formula would give **five** candies to the child.

Instead, break into disjoint cases, and add up:
The cases are $MWAB, MWAC, MWBC, MABC, WABC$

For $MWAB$, e.g., number of ways will be $\binom51\binom61\binom31\binom41$

After adding up for each case, to get the $Pr$,  divide by $\binom{19}4$

Answer (score 1):

The probability of selecting 4 distinct items, when selecting 4 from partitions of sizes 5, 6, 3, 4, and 1, is:

$$\bbox[lemonchiffon, 2ex]{\color{black}{\sum_{\substack{}a+b+c+d+e=4\\(a,b,c,d,e)\in\{0,1\}^5}\dfrac{\dbinom 5 a\dbinom 6 b\dbinom 3 c\dbinom 4 d\dbinom 1 e}{\dbinom{5+6+3+4+1}{4}}=\frac 1{3876}\sum_{\substack{}a+b+c+d+e=4\\(a,b,c,d,e) \in\{0,1\}^5}{5}^a{6}^b{3}^c{4}^d\color{silver}{1^e}}}$$

Then its a matter of summing the term for all $(a,b,c,d,e)$ that are permutations of $(1,1,1,1,0)$

Comment: Very nice arrangement. (+1)